# Create a method in Interface which gets called periodically - Java

Tags: java, android, interface, location, abstract-class

I would like to create an interface which contains a method A() that gets called periodically. A common example would be onLocationChanged() method of LocationListner in Android.

If someone implements my interface then A() should get called when I get some new readings from server.

How can I achieve this ?

**Edit:**

I would like to create a method which functions similar to `onLocationChanged` of `LocationListener` interface in Android. 
Whenever I get new data I want to pass it to this method and who ever implements my interface should get the new data in that method.

Comment: Is this for a library that people embed in their own apps? Or do you want other apps to communicate with your app?

Comment: Could you please ellaborate a little more

Comment: @Thilo I want to use the interface within my app itself

Comment: @therealprashant can you please help me out with some code ?

Comment: @therealprashant i have edited of question

Comment: That do able . You can implement your method as a foreground service which will keep running and only the user can destroy it. And regarding the data you want to process on just put the logic in your code. But foreground service is what you looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you create an interface like this:

```
public interface MyListener {
    public void a(int data);
}
```

This is your server class:

```
public class Server {
    private MyListener mListener;

    public static void setListener(MyListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    /**
    * This is the method you should call when you get new data
    */
    private void doSomeWork() {
        int data = 0;
        // Process data
        if(mListener != null)
            mListener.a(data);
    }
}
```

Then you can implement like this to receive data:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Blah blah blah
        Server.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void a(int data) {
        // You can receive the data here
    }

}
```